# Populating an Amazon DynamoDB table with initial data python CDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm new to CDK and am wondering if I am able to pre populate my dynamoDB table with an existing JSON in the CDK. I saw people recommending using custom resources but I am not sure about the syntax of it in python. Can someone help me out?

```
class ApplicationLayer(Construct):
    #for what
    @property
    def handler(self):
        return self._handler
        
    @property
    def table(self):
        return self._table
    
    
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id:str, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(scope,id,**kwargs)
        
        self._table = ddb.Table(
            self, 'tasks',
            partition_key = {'name':'tenant_id', 'type': ddb.AttributeType.NUMBER},
            sort_key = {'name':'task_id','type':ddb.AttributeType.NUMBER}
        )
```

Comment: See the [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/custom-resources-readme.html) docs. You'll create a custom resource that depends on the DynamoDB table and write a Lambda function handler that, when invoked, populates the DynamoDB table with whatever items you need. Use boto3 in your custom Lambda function to interface to DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in using Python to populate a DynamoDB table - then look at using the **AWS SDK for Python**. See this example that shows how to use the AWS SDK for Python (Boto3) with Amazon DynamoDB to create and use a table that stores data about movies. Included in this example is how to use a JSON file to load a table:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/python/example_code/dynamodb/GettingStarted/scenario_getting_started_movies.pyle:

Answer (score 0):

[constructs.dev](https://constructs.dev/) has [aws-cdk-dynamodb-seeder](https://constructs.dev/packages/aws-cdk-dynamodb-seeder/v/1.56.1?lang=typescript) that can help you with that. It doesn't support CDK v2 yet.

Install the package:

```
pip install aws-cdk-dynamodb-seeder==1.56.1
```

Use it:

```
# Example automatically generated without compilation. See https://github.com/aws/jsii/issues/826
from aws_cdk_dynamodb_seeder import Seeder
my_table = Table(stack, "MyTable",
    table_name="MyTable",
    partition_key={"name": "Id", "type": AttributeType.STRING}
)
Seeder(stack, "MySeeder",
    table=my_table,
    setup=require("./items-to-put.json"),
    teardown=require("./keys-to-delete.json"),
    refresh_on_update=True
)
```